# does "Javascript:" works on mozilla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, element

I have an mouse event link like below.
In IE8 when i mouseover on link, a blank iframe appear (this part is done by the help of stackoverflow friends :) ) . but in mozilla nothing happens. even in console nothing happens. This was my first problem. the second is why the iframe is blank and nothing is shown?
can u help me to figure this out?
thanx
The codes Are below:

```
   <a href="javascript:">
          <div id="idAdminMenu" onmouseover="Dropdown(idAdminMenu,idAdminMenuDrop,iAdminMenuWidth)" >
          <%=GetLanguagePhrase(11)%>
          <!--Admin-->
```

and the function is :

```
function Dropdown (oMenu,oMenuDropDown) {

    // Construct the element purely in JS:
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.className = 'adframe';
    iframe.id = '111';
    iframe.name = 'widget';
    iframe.width = 207;
    iframe.height = 100;
    iframe.marginWidth = 0;
    iframe.marginHeight = 0;
    iframe.frameBorder = 0;
    iframe.scrolling = 'no';
    // Set the position:
    iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    iframe.style.top = '70px'; // Change this value to what you need
    iframe.style.left = '370px'; // Change this value to what you need
    // Set the contents:
    var sHTML = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css"></head><body topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bottommargin="0" style="overflow:visible;border-width:0px">' + oMenuDropDown.innerHTML + '</body></html>';
   // iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURI(sHTML);
  iframe.src = encodeURI(sHTML);
    // Show popup:
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);}
```

Comment: Mozilla disabled javascript URIs since FF 6 I believe - you have to run from a bookmarklet or Firefox Addon to run them

Comment: Thanx.
But The second problem is still remains. :(